# Вывод товаров из определённой категории или определённого списка товаров Wordpress WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В шаблоне вывод страницы категории товаров выводится вот так:

```
<div class="wrap_content wrap_content_2 promo-page">
    <?php
    $content_parts = get_extended($post->post_content);
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_parts['extended']);
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_parts['main']);
    ?>
</div>
```

потому что там между описанием вставлены товары из категорий.

Вопрос: как здесь вывести либо товары только из этой категории, без учёта дочерних категорий, либо определённый список товаров (штук 8-12 выбрано для показа)?

Всякие `new WP_Query($args)` почему-то не срабатывают, даже с `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: @Kjuri Для тех кто знает ВП не нужно уточнять "что за функция". https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_extended. А вот зачем в тему лезут те, кто не в зуб ногой - вот это было всегда интересно.

Comment: Причём тут get_extended? Учи назначение функций. А [не]вывод дочерних настраивается в кастомайзере.

Comment: @SeVlad get_extended для разделения поста и вставки товаров между частями текста.
Есть метод в $post->post_content выводить другой список товаров?

Comment: Выше ссылка на описание функции. Изучай.